# Mongoid + ActiveModel validation + I18n, not properly translating attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, mongoid, activemodel

I am trying to internationalize the attributes of my `Booking` model

From my fr.yml :

```
  attributes: &attributes
    booking:
      first_name: 'Prénom'
      last_name: 'Nom'
      email: "Email"
      phone: 'Téléphone'

  activemodel:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
    attributes:
      <<: *attributes
```

When I spawn a rails console :

```
2.0.0p0 :011 > I18n.t(:activemodel)[:attributes][:booking]
 => {:first_name=>"Prénom", :last_name=>"Nom", :email=>"Email", :phone=>"Téléphone"}
```

but :

```
2.0.0p0 :013 > Booking.human_attribute_name('first_name')
 => "First name"
```

However, on my web server, the errors are still english + french, such as :

"First name doit être rempli(e)"

What am I missing ? I'm using mongoid, ruby 2.0.0 and rails 3.2.11.

Note that I am using `model.errors.full_messages` to retrieve the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it :

```
mongoid:
  attributes:
    <<: *attributes
```

It seems that even if `Mongoid::Document` includes `ActiveModel::Validation`, you have to define a separate key for the translation.